# What gives 5% critical hit chance and 50% critical damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

I did not have anything equipped:

[image: Screenshot showing the character stat details and inventory]

But I still had 5% critical hit chance and 50% critical damage. What causes this?

*Update:* [Broken Promises](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/broken-promises)

@Aequitas, @Chippies: 5% CHC means 1 of 20 hits is critical. And this means 3 of 4 times one will get the 3 seconds. Being able to do 2 attacks per second means that you have less than 6 successful hits, probably 4. The bottom line is for more than 5 non critical hits one will get less than 5 critical hits. And this equals to less than 50% CHC, which is almost the same as putting CHC on every item.  And this means the ring is nice but not exceptional. If it would be possible to get 0% CHC, the ring would be exceptional, because then it would be possible to get more than 50% CHC overall.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the base level all Diablo III characters have.

> Characters have a base 5% crit chance and a base 50% crit damage

[Wiki link](http://www.diablowiki.net/Critical_hit)

Comment: Is there a way to get 0% critical hit chance?

Comment: @ceving Nope, impossible

Comment: @ceving why would you even want to?

Comment: @Aequitas to get the most out of Broken Promises, for one

Comment: Broken Promises would be by far the best ring in the game if 0% crit chance was possible, which is why 5% base is needed for balance purposes. As it is now, even with 5% cc, Broken Promises is good, but not irreplaceable.

Comment: @Chippies at the risk of digressing too much in comments, I think you're overselling BP, even at 0 CHC. It's ICD is fairly high compared to its uptime, and you really only make your crit rate back on superfast bursty builds, like U6 monk. On anything else, it a straight downgrade, especially compared to the other big rings like Unity, CoE, the BoW set or RoRG. That's the last I'll say on the subject here in the comments.